# Encryption failed after turning my android phone on

Tags: rom-flashing, fastboot, boot, stock-android, hardware

when i turn on my phone it shows "Encryption failed" and "Unable to start up your device. the encryption process was interrupted. you need to reset your device to factory default setting. this will erase all your data " and it has a reset button. this reset button and flashing my phone with Odin does not help. how can i make it work again?

Comment: Which files did you use? You should flash "repair firmware" which clear the memory. In the other hand, this can be a hardware failure meaning the flash memory is damaged

Comment: when i turn on the phone it shows "encryption failed" and it says you should factory reset your phone and there is a reset button which is factory reset . but it does not work

Comment: you said you did flash it with Odin!

Comment: yes but the problem is still there . after installing  new software or factory reset , it still says "encryption failed" on startup

Comment: Any idea on what did cause this? It seems to me that this can be a hardware failure with the eMMC chip

Comment: it was on my hand when it suddenly freezed then i had to wait until its battrey runs out of charge . when i turned on this showed up

Comment: here is a shot of the problem https://imgur.com/a/JEKmdXW

Comment: Ok, I guess the file system is compromised. You just need to flash the whole firmware. Download the so called "repair firmware" then flash it with Odin. Leave all options to default while flashing. Should solve this

Comment: What is the model number? Should be printed on the back and start by SM-

Comment: it is galaxy A8+ SM-A730F

Comment: Well, grab these files from here: https://www.full-repair-firmware.com/2018/01/repair-firmware-a730f.html?m=1

Comment: i downloaded as you said, with pit file Odin failed and without pit file it is still encryption error  :-(

Comment: So I'm afraid that your memory chip is damage. You'll need to bring it to a repair shop to get it fixed as they have advanced tools that can access the memory directory